# WMI RegDword getvalue and setvalue

Tags: c#, registry, wmi

I can't get REG_DWORD data from USBSTOR registry key, but I can get 'DisplayName' data of REG_SZ type

```
ManagementScope myScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + strComputer + "\\root\\default");
ManagementPath mypath = new ManagementPath("StdRegProv");
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(myScope, mypath, null);
ManagementBaseObject inParams = mc.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
inParams["sSubKeyName"] = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR";
inParams["sValueName"] = "DisplayName";
ManagementBaseObject outParams = mc.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);
Console.WriteLine(outParams["Type"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [GetDWORDValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390445%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method if data type is REG_DWORD and [GetStringValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390788%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method if data type is REG_SZ:

```
ManagementBaseObject inParams = mc.GetMethodParameters("GetDWORDValue");
inParams["sSubKeyName"] = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR";
inParams["sValueName"] = "Type";
ManagementBaseObject outParams = mc.InvokeMethod("GetDWORDValue", inParams, null);
UInt32 uValue = (UInt32)outParams["uValue"];
//...
ManagementBaseObject inParams = mc.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
inParams["sSubKeyName"] = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR";
inParams["sValueName"] = "DisplayName";
ManagementBaseObject outParams = mc.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);
string sValue = (string)outParams["sValue"];
```

Comment: DimitryG if the driver of the USB i aleardy installed and i set the start value to 4 the usb will run but if it is the first time it wont is that true ? and if i want to prevent it even if the driver is intalled do u know any method?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't give you the exact answer on this question. Please, check [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823732)

Comment: from this article I can discover why  you can't give methe exact answer but thanks for u help